# Inserting and removing elements from an array while maintaining the array to be sorted

Tags: c++, c, sorting, priority-queue

I'm wondering whether somebody can help me with this problem. I'm using C/C++ to program and I need to do the following:

I am given a sorted array P (biggest first) containing floats. It usually has a very big size.. sometimes holding correlation values from 10 megapixel images. I need to iterate through the array until it is empty. Within the loop there is additional processing taking place.

The gist of the problem is that at the start of the loop, I need to remove the elements with the maximum value from the array, check certain conditions and if they hold, then I need to reinsert the elements into the array but after decreasing their value. However, I want the array to be efficiently sorted after the reinsertion.

Can somebody point me towards a way of doing this? I have tried the naive approach of re-sorting everytime I insert, but that seems really wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the data structure. Repeatedly accessing the largest element, and then quickly inserting new values, in such a way that you can still efficiently repeatedly access the largest element, is a job for a [**heap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), which may be [fairly easily created from your array in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/).

BTW, please don't talk about "C/C++". There is no such language. You're instead making vague implications about the style in which you're writing things, most of which will strike experienced programmers as bad.

Comment: The term `heap` has another more common meaning in C and C++, a more thorough description or link would be helpful.

Comment: In C++, the priority_queue is such a heap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.. I did look up max-rooted heaps and priority queue's.. but there is a slight nuance here in that I have to deal with all equal array values as a group. What I mean is that I have to remove not just the maximum element but all the elements having the maximum value (if there are more than one).. can I do this with a heap ?

Comment: You can pop the max element, and then check if the top of the heap has the same value, and repeatedly pop until it no longer does.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/, as it is designed to do just this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a binary search to determine where to insert the changed value after you removed it from the array. Note that inserting or removing at the front or somewhere in the middle is not very efficient either, as it requires moving all items with a higher index up or down, respectively.

ISTM that you should rather put your changed items into a new array and sort that once, after you finished iterating over the original array. If memory is a problem, and you really have to do things in place, change the values in place and only sort once.

I can't think of a better way to do this. Keeping the array sorted all the time seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is already sorted, you can use a binary search to find the location to insert the updated value. C++ provides `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` for this purpose, C provides `bsearch`. Just shift all the existing values up by one location in the array and store the new value at the newly cleared spot.

Comment: Having to shift all the elements for insertion all the time will pretty much cancel out the benefit of keeping things sorted in the first place, I imagine. Either way it's O(N) each time, and the use of `std::lower_bound` becomes only a constant-factor improvement.

Comment: @Karl It's O(N) in the *worst case*. Depending on the scenario, this may be an acceptable solution (it so happens I was thinking of exactly the same thing!) If the array contains values such as 100 99 96 90 85 82 80 ... and the values are being decreased by, say 10 -- it's not too bad at all to do it this way. Edit: Mark's answer may be slightly misleading in that it says you have to shift "all the existing elements". In an array sorted in descending order, for example, you only have to shift the elements that are greater than the adjusted value, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: priority_queue does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode that may work decently if you aren't decreasing the removed values by much:

For example, say you're processing the element with the maximum value in the array, and say the array is sorted in descending order (largest first).

1. Remove `array[0]`.
2. Let `newVal = array[0] - adjustment`, where `adjustment` is the amount you're decreasing the value by.
3. Now loop through, adjusting only the values you need to:

Pseudocode:

```
i = 0
while (newVal < array[i]) {
  array[i] = array[i+1];
  i++;
}
array[i] = newVal;
swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
```

Again, if you're not decreasing the removed values by a large amount (relative to the values in the array), this could work fairly efficiently.

Of course, the generally better alternative is to use a more appropriate data structure, such as a heap.

Comment: "generally better alternative is to use a more appropriate data structure, such as a heap." seems to be the important part.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using another temporary array could help.

This way you can first sort the "changed" elements alone.

And after that just do a regular merge O(n) for the two sub-arrays to the temp array, and copy everything back to the original array.

Comment: It would have to be merged every time, which would be slower than simply re-inserting the same data.

Comment: But as I understood, he needs to remove the elements with the maximum value from the array, then reinsert them into the array after decreasing their value. So all "changed" values will be received at once... Which means only one merge is needed...

Comment: Yes, but a merge can't be done in place, which means you have to touch 3N data.  With a simple shift-and-insert of some sort (like vector::insert), UP TO N are touched, in place.